# AngularJS performances on very big form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, performance

We are currently working on an application with many data to dispay. Everything works well so far and we will now start to build some forms. We are looking to use the Angular form/validation system. But i can't find good informations for performances. Our forms will contains many (let's say 200) fields. With some complex fields like datepickers. Many fields have constraints between them and must change their values when a field is changed somewhere in the form.

- Is there any thing to know ? Maybe we should avoid the use of some feature ?
- Is it possible to build it with the Angular form system or should we use a custom/faster system ?

I edit my question for more informations : I already know about `$digest` and `$apply` cycles. I already know how watchers works. I already know how to tune them all. Our application can already display a massive number of elements in the page (like 1000 documents in a search). We know how to avoid slow things of angular in this part of the application.

But, we don't have forms at the moment. And we will start to build them. I'm looking for example of Angular applications with very big forms and acceptable performances. And blog article saying that the AngularJS form system just can't handle that. If we have to build our own form framework to avoid the AngularJS form system, we are capable to do that without any problem.

Comment: This is kind of an open-ended (broad) question: Is there anything to know? That covers pretty much all of Angular. You should really think about designing your forms such that they don't have 200 fields on one page...

Comment: Flagged as too broad. **There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.**

Comment: We were facing the same problem but we solved it. True, there are some limitions due to view port performance but rendering a form with 200 element should be no problem. Especially subrenderes like `datepicker` and `selects` break our performance. Lets speak in [chat]?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130538/its-a-room

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a very broad topic and can have numerous causes.  You should really start by understanding the `$digest` cycle and how each model update is causing that.

[Angular Docs for ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) may help your idea.  The article from [YearOfMoo](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html) may help as well.  Otherwise you may need to dig further on `$digest` cycles